# What steps do I need to take to repaint plaster walls?

Tags: walls, paint, plaster

What steps do I need to take to paint over already painted white plaster walls with a slight glossy finish?

This might be a dumb question but my walls are I think plaster and I’m looking to paint over them with an eggshell paint. What sort of prep work do I need to do to ensure that the paint properly sticks to this wall? It seems a bit glossy and I’m afraid that will prevent it from adhering. Do I need to strip this paint is there a certain primer I need to get? I’ve never painted anything before so any and all help will be greatly appreciated. [image: photo of wall]

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], please take the [tour]. What research have you done on painting over a gloss paint? There have to be dozens of questions on this site alone, and 1000s on the internet in general. Please [edit] to indicate some amount of research on your part. If you hover your cursor over the "up vote" button, you'll note that it says, "This question shows research effort...", while the "down vote" hover text says, "This question does not show any research effort...". We expect you to put in _some_ effort before asking.

Comment: Reading up on [how to write a good answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), should help you understand what's expected here.

Answer (score 0):

The basis of your question makes me believe that this is a "new to you home".

First clean the walls. Use a good degreaser like TSP in a bucket of water or some of the popular degreasing dish soap. There is no need to strip off the old paint.  ( it would be a disaster anyway.)

Consult your paint store.  Usually the wall should be primed, however newer paint have been developed with paint and primer together.  The paint pros can advise you. They can recommend the proper primer or paint/primer for your project.

From experience, I can tell you clean walls that have been primered will take new paint very well. I have had very good results with the newer paint and primer combos as well.